# Warning when binding properties of dynamically created QML objects in JavaScript

Tags: qml, qt5

**Edit2:** The accepted answer demonstrates how the warning should not pose that much of a problem. I have changed the topic of the question to better reflect what is in fact answered there. It did not solve the question of Binding refered to in Edit1, but as the warning does not worry me anymore the primary reason for using Binding is no longer relevant.

**Edit:** As per Praveen Kumar's suggestion I created a MVCE to illustrate the problem. However, the code now seems to work as intended! However, because the method used has an explicit warning in the documentation, I have added the condition to the question that the solution has to involve the Binding QML Type, which is still something I do not understand how to do.

**Modified original question:** I have some objects that I create dynamically in QML, and I would like to bind some of these objects' properties to properties of static objects.

I have used a ListModel to manage the dynamically created objects as suggested [here](https://qmlbook.github.io/en/ch13/index.html#tracking-dynamic-objects).

Using this ListModel I have no problem looping through all the objects and accessing them.

The same site suggests using [the Binding component](https://qmlbook.github.io/en/ch13/index.html#binding-indirectly) for binding properties, but I do not understand how to use it.

I am able to make this work *without* the Binding type as the following code demonstrates:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    ListModel
    {
        id: listModel
    }

    Column
    {
        id: mainCol
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        spacing: 10

        Button
        {
            text: "Click to create object"

            onClicked:
            {
                var component = Qt.createComponent("Box.qml");
                var obj = component.createObject(mainCol);

                listModel.append({"obj": obj})
            }
        }

        TextField
        {
            id: inputTxt
        }

        Button
        {
            text: "Click to bind properties"

            onClicked:
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < listModel.count; ++i)
                {
                    var dynObj = listModel.get(i).obj;
                    dynObj.boxTxt = Qt.binding(function() {return inputTxt.text});
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Box.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle
{
    property alias boxTxt: txt.text

    width: 100
    height: 100
    color: "lightblue"

    Text
    {
        id: txt
        text: "Dynamic object"
    }
}
```

This does exactly what I want, but the documentation has this warning  about ListModel.get():

> **Warning:** The returned object is not guaranteed to remain valid. It should not be used in property bindings.

which is what I'm doing.

I can not wrap my head around using Binding. Wouldn't I have to dynamically create a new Binding component for each Box component? And would this not get me equally far?

If Binding is not the way to do this, that would be an interesting answer as well!

(Also, if editing the question this way is not the way to do things here, please let me know in a comment)

Comment: Can you provide [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks! I created a MVCE and the code worked as intendend. There must be something else going on in the code at work. However, the method I'm using is, I believe, not robust, so I have changed the question accordingly.

Comment: If below mentioned description has answered your question/doubts then please accept the answer so that others can refer it in future. Its really very well described.

Comment: I accepted it and changed the topic of the question to better reflect that answer, thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry that I have so little time to think about what you try... I don't really get, why you should add visual objects to a `ListModel`, but there might be reasons...

As far as I understood is your problem with the warning:

> **Warning:** The returned object is not guaranteed to remain valid. It should not be used in property bindings.

so I want to tell you that you should not experience much problems because of this warning.

So let's see why (and what you are doing)

```
onClicked: {
    var component = Qt.createComponent("Box.qml");
    var obj = component.createObject(mainCol);

    listModel.append({"obj": obj})
}
```

Here you create the object with `mainCol` as it's parent. To have it destroyed, you need to destroy `mainCol` or call `destroy()` on the object explicitly.
As long as you don't do that, you don't need to fear that the create object becomes invalid.

Now you append a new `JSObject` to the `ListModel` which holds a reference to your newly created Item.

Then you have:

```
        onClicked:
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < listModel.count; ++i)
            {
                var dynObj = listModel.get(i).obj;
                dynObj.boxTxt = Qt.binding(function() {return inputTxt.text});
            }
        }
```

Now: `listModel.get(i)` will return an object which is handled by the JS Garbage Collector, meaning that, as soon as there is nothing referencing it anymore and the GC has a run, the object will be trashed. (Ideally. Sometimes the GC is a bit greedy!)
If now, you had a binding to to said object, the binding would lose the connection (as this might not be a reference, valued by the GC), so it would be no good idea to have something like this:

```
var dObj = listModel.get(i)
property var x = Qt.binding(function() { return dObj })
```

But you don't do that. In fact you are using the reference to the Item you created earlier, that you stuffed in the `ListModel` to bind a property of this `Item`. For this you read the reference *once* in the line

```
var dynObj = listModel.get(i).obj;
```

Now you don't need to bother for the life time of the object that had just the job of telling you the reference (returned by `listModel.get(i)`) anymore, as you have what you want (`.obj`) assigned (not *bound*). It can die if it wants, you go on with the binding as *you want*.

Without following the exact usecase, a `ObjectModel` might be (at least as much) suit your needs. To my understanding this in a container to store references to Items.

Comment: Thanks! Very interesting! I'm not sure I _completely_ follow, but from what you are saying I understand that get() returns a _reference_ to the object, and this reference might get picked up by the GC. However, I simply use this reference to access a property of the _actual_ object ("behind" the reference, so to speak), and therefore this is not a problem?